# How to create chart in excel to show uptime and downtime availability

Tags: excel, charts

I have sets of data like this:

[image]

And want to make a chart that looks like this in excel:

[image]

And I want to have the x-axis showing date 1-Jan until 31-Dec.
How to make a chart like that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming related questions only, how to graph data in Excel is not on-topic here.

Comment: Owh, sorry. When I search the answer in Google, I found some search results from stack overflow but still not match with my needs. That's why I directly asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is slightly offtopic, I outline an answer as a starting point, as my solution would use **VBA**.

You could use a **XY-Chart** and **VBA** to add new data rows.

[image]

## Some notes

- Each *Unit* has an unique *Y value* assigned to it.
- The first two (number of unique units) rows below the headline (1 & 2) are used to draw the green area, which start at 1st January and ends `NOW()`.
- The remaining rows are used to draw each *downtime* piece. They should be added via a macro.

## Chart settings

- Set *X axis* **min** and **max** to **01. Jan 2021** resp. **31. Dec 2021**
- Set **line width** to *40 px* and **End type** to *flat*

## Tweaks

- Define the number of main labels on x axis
- Add a datarow with (x=44197) and (y=Unit) to include *Unit labels* (Add labels, position left, show values in range,...)